# -Formatting date dropdown width using bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the default rails date input for a search form (automatically generated dropdown inputs for date, year, and month).

I am using bootstrap to style my form.

Currently, the form looks like this:

[image]

But as you can see in the code below, I am trying to have the month/date/year inputs be side by side.

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
    <div id="header" id="index-header" class="header-slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="quick-search">
              <div class="row">
                <form role="form">
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="country">Area</label>
                      <%= f.select( :area_id_eq, Area.all.collect {|a| [ a.name, a.id ] }, {:prompt => "Any Area"}, class:'form-control')%>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="bedroom">Rental Type</label>
                        <%= f.select( :rental_type_id_eq, RentalType.all.collect {|r| [ r.name, r.id ] }, {:prompt => "Short or Long Term"}, class:'form-control') %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Minimum Bedrooms</label>
                      <%= f.number_field :beds_gteq, :step => 0.5, class:'form-control', value: 1 %>    
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="bathroom">Date Needed</label>
                      <%= f.date_select :from_date_lteq, {:prompt => { day: 'Any date', month: 'Any month', year: 'Any year' }, :default => nil, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => Date.today.year + 2, :order => [:month, :day, :year]}, {class: 'form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3'} %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <%= f.submit "Search", class:'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block' %>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

How can I format these dropdowns using bootstrap within the rails date form helper?

Comment: add a class to the `form-group` containing those date fields, and in that class use `display: inline`, and also add something to change the width of the select in that class as well, something like `select { width: 25% }`.

Comment: @fanta can you please clarify the second part? This generated an error                       <%= f.date_select :from_date_lteq, {:prompt => { day: 'Any date', month: 'Any month', year: 'Any year' }, :default => nil, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => Date.today.year + 2, :order => [:month, :day, :year]}, {class: 'form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3'}, {width: 25%} %>

Comment: put `select { width: 25% }` in the same css class where you put `display: inline`.